# How should i check whether the string first character is in capital? i want to check through user input

Tags: java

Actually i wanted to check the condition that the input sentence has its first letter already in capital 
The code below is converting the lowercase character of first letter in the string to upper case i wanted to add the line if suppose user enter a string like "I Am Human Being" means in this the first character is already in upper case then how to add a line to the existing code

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String line=sc.nextLine();
String uc="";
Scanner line_sc=new Scanner(line);
while(line_sc.hasNext()) {
    String word=line_sc.next();
    uc+=Character.toUppercase(word.charAt(0))+ word.substring(1)+" ";
}
System.out.println(uc.trim());
```

Comment: its different bro try to look in the code

Comment: I trust you to be able to understand other SO posts and transfer the gained knowledge to your problem at hand. The linked answer contains all the relevant information.

Comment: @luk2302 please check its different and you are even degrading my points

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
String str = "input";
String capital = str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);

return str.equals(capital);
```

or even better:

```
return Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(0));
```

Comment: The first answer won't work since the "==" comparison between two objects (here, two Strings) won't return true unless both have the same address. Please change this comparison to `str.equals(capital)`

Comment: RIght, just changed.

Comment: No sir its not i wanted to print a output not to return the sentence

Comment: what is exactly the result you want?

Comment: If user enters Hello I Am Human Being then it must print the first character of the string is already in caps

Comment: @Ragnarok we have shown you *how* to determine wether the first char is uppercase or not. **Please** try to **understand** how that works and transfer that knowledge. That is such a basic thing to do, you **have** to be able to do that.

Comment: I showed you how to check if the first char is capital. Shouldn't be difficult to print it.